# Html Absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I have div, which position is set to absolute. Also I have couple paragraphs inside of it. When I move right side of explorer to the left, the paragraphs move with it and try to adjust to size of window. I tried to position them absolutely, but them still move. How can I set that div or paragraphs inside it, so they remain on the same spot? Please... Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="search_slogan" > <!-- search_slogan Slogan--> 
    <p style="font-size: 26px; ">  Free Business Name Search </p>
    <p style="font-family:gothic; "> Enter any potential business name.
        We'll let you know if the company name is available for use in your state, </p>
    <p style="font-family:gothic; "> usually within 1 business day. </p>
</div> <!-- END search_slogan Slogan-->
```

CSS:

```
#search_slogan{
    line-height: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 200px;
    font-family:basic_gothic;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? That way it is clearer for us to see what is happening. ;)

Comment: Moving to fit the window is usually a desirable state. If you don't have it, then you tend to have something that looks wrong for anyone with a different window size to you. What's the actual problem? It sounds like you need to provide a lot more context.

Comment: Copy and paste it @Jerodev, it would have been quicker than you asking for it. But for the lazy (like above), it's here:  http://jsfiddle.net/4440jkwn/

Comment: @nicael You have no idea haha, I gave up in the end.

Comment: The problem is that I want my div to remain on the same spot.. I have there absolute position, which supposed to mean that if I change the size of my window, the div will stay on its place. Instead the part of the text collapses on the next line.

Comment: Like this? Remove the line-height... http://jsfiddle.net/4440jkwn/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem might be that your box has no set width, so it fills the space remaining.

Add a set width like below and it won't move anymore.

```
#search_slogan{
  line-height: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  font-family:basic_gothic;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

There are additional solutions with things like hiding the overflow, but setting the width is the simplest.

Comment: Please mark the check box next to the answer you select =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was your `line:height` property, that was set to 15%.  That will cause letters to pile up.  I cleanen up your HTML and created a [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/x8yjLf0s/).